# EF tracking vs non-tracking

Tags: c#, entity-framework

When do I want to have tracking enabled and when I want it disabled in a WebAPI? It almost seems like I would always want to use this:

```
context.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;
```

with my `DbContext` and only when I need to persist an object I would mark the object as modified. Could you give me a specific example when I need to have tracking enabled and when I want it to be disabled?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First Let's understand what exactly is tracking , [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/tracking) is a good reading about it but in short :

> Tracking behavior controls if Entity Framework Core will keep
>   information about an entity instance in its change tracker. If an
>   entity is tracked, any changes detected in the entity will be
>   persisted to the database during SaveChanges().

```
var blog = context.Blogs.SingleOrDefault(b => b.BlogId == 1);
blog.Rating = 5;
context.SaveChanges();
```

as you can see in the above example if the query is tracked (which is default behavior) you don't even need to mark the object as modified , because this object is retrieved by the context it's **attached** to it and the context will notice changes preformed on it and persist it we `SaveChanges()` is called

So to answer your questions: it depends on the scenario ,if you are sure that you will not modify the retrieved data and won't need to persist any changes that you might perform on it then there is no point in using a tracked query , in fact it would benefit the performance if you used a No-Tracking query .

Think of No-Tracking queries as read-only data that you just want to retrieve to display to the user or extract some info from it

the mentioned articular talks about EF core but the tracking vs no-tracking concept are the same even in other ORMs

Answer (score 6):

The only context instances I use `QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking` are Reporting contexts, not API contexts unless the API applicable to that context is entirely read-only.

`NoTracking` will provide a nominal speed boost for data Read operations.

You can use `NoTracking` for update operations, but you will require a bit of additional code, and incur a nominal penalty for Updates. If you are building an Append-only (Inserts, no Updates) then `NoTracking` provides no penalty.

Why: When EF loads an entity with tracking, 2 things happen. First, the reference is loaded into the local cache. Second, a proxy is used which keeps track of updates against fields on the entity.

Given an update accepting a new Message for a Record entity:

```
void UpdateMessage(int recordId, string message);
```

With tracking:

```
void UpdateMessage(int recordId, string message)
{
    using(var context = new AppContext())
    {
         var record = context.Records.Single(x => x.RecordId == recordId);
         record.Message = message;
         context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Without tracking:

```
void UpdateMessage(int recordId, string message)
{
    using(var context = new AppContext())
    {
         var record = context.Records.AsNoTracking().Single(x => x.RecordId == recordId);
         record.Message = message;
         context.Update(record); // or Attach() and set Modified state.
         context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

These look very similar on the surface, but there is a distinct difference that will happen under the hood:

In the first case, EF will generate an SQL statement similar to:

```
UPDATE tblRecords SET Message = @1 WHERE RecordId = @0
```

In the second case, EF will generate:

```
UPDATE tblRecords SET Message = @1, SomeField = @2, SomeOtherField = @3, CreatedAt = @4, CreatedBy = @5 WHERE RecordId = @0
```

When taking untracked entities and "Updating" them, EF has no idea *what* changed, so every column is updated. With tracking, only fields that were updated will be in the query. For larger entities this can be noticeable.

Inserts, including for append-only systems aren't affected since these would include all columns anyways.

Answer (score 4):

WebAPI will always have NoTracking.

Tracking is required when you do a fetch and then you make changes(updates) to the same object that was fetched. Now if you save that object back to DB, then tracking makes sense.

This is never the case in WebAPI.

Answer (score 1):

If you are projecting to *viewmodels* and/or sending over-the-wire, etc... tracking will not have a difference, and is a slight performance hit.

If you are doing more complicated queries where you are pulling data into memory and mutating it, then tracking makes more sense as it allows you to modify an entity and call `SaveChanges` again.

It's as simple as that.